# How compatible are GWT Maven Plugin and Google Plugin 2.3?

Tags: gwt, maven-plugin, gwt-designer

I have not been able to make the gwt:eclipse create a Launch that will work with the Plugin (the arguments tab is empty). So I am wondering how compatible it is with the Google Plugin:
- Will I be able to use the GWT Designer?
- Will I be able to run in Hosted Mode
- Will I be able to run GWTTests?

The steps I followed are:
 - Use the Archetype to create Maven Project
 - Import the project
 - Go to the project properties and enable the Web Toolkit from the Google folder
 - Copy my *.gwt.xml file to src/main/java
 - run gwt:eclpse to create a Launch file (Which does not show in Run As by the way)

In the end it seems that I have to create a Run Configuration by hand. So how compatible are these 2 tools?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Each version of the GWT maven plugin is linked to a GWT version.

When you use GWT maven plugin, you need to check that the version used by the plugin is the same of your project and the same of the Google Eclipse plugin (configured per project).

The two plugins seem to be compatible (I use both without problems).

What I've done to create the project :
- create a maven project using the archetype gwt.
- import the projet in eclipse using import > existing maven project 
- make your project a GWT project (project properties and check "enable GWT").
- run as web application (gwt) via the google eclipse plugin and not maven gwt:eclipse.